# Source for a quotation from a Rabbi (or Jewish story)

Tags: sources-mekorot, rabbis, quotations, story-identification

My apologies if this question isn't within the typical scope of this site. I'm trying to locate the source of a quotation I saved long ago, it was from I believe an academic text collecting various rabbinical "teaching stories", but I can't remember much more.

The quote is:

> *I know there are questions that have no answers; there is a suffering that has no shame; there is injustice in God’s creation—and there are reasons enough for man to explode with rage. I know there are reasons for you to be angry. Good. Let us be angry. Together.*

And I further seem recall this was a story of the Rabbi in question talking to a young man struggling with doubt and seeking to leave his village/community because of doubts and spiritual struggles (it was an old story, not by a modern Jewish thinker).

There's a part of me that keeps thinking this quote is by (or associated with) Rebbe Nachman of Bratslav, but I can't actually find a source for that. In any event I would be very grateful of any assistance, sources, or confirmation of authorship, all are helpful.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When doing a google search I came across two Christian books one [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ae9JAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT173&lpg=PT173&dq=Rabbi%20-%20%22Let%20us%20be%20angry%20together%22.&source=bl&ots=COo0FCLGXf&sig=ACfU3U0pD_kijQkDkuT1dTheXxfVvokFMQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwic7cft_KXyAhVNY8AKHcoaBlUQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=Rabbi%20-%20%22Let%20us%20be%20angry%20together%22.&f=false) and the other [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wDJfDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=Rabbi%20-%20%22Let%20us%20be%20angry%20together%22.&source=bl&ots=1R2s7YkWUS&sig=ACfU3U0GMlk_a47AaT5naV0Yo1iA8BT7FA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwic7cft_KXyAhVNY8AKHcoaBlUQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=Rabbi%20-%20%22Let%20us%20be%20angry%20together%22.&f=false) which attribute it to the Chasidic master [Rav Baruch of Medzebozh/Medzhybizh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boruch_of_Medzhybizh) who was the grandson of the founder of chassidus, the Baal Shem Tov and uncle of Rav Nachman of Breslov.

After doing a bit more research it is also brought down in [Elie Wiesel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elie_Wiesel)'s book *[Four Hasidic Masters and Their Struggle against Melancholy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0268009473)* produced by the Notre Dame Press. The quote features on p.60 and is quoted in the book review by Robert McAfee Brown available [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40062482) (although you need access through a relevant academic institution) or [here](https://ur.booksc.eu/book/28051993/57e4b0) (click on the download icon)

Comment: Thank you so much! The book by Elie Wiesel was exactly the text in question. And thank you too for the extra sources as well, phenomenally thorough answer.